# i get a recursion error while running this

Tags: python

Write a function number_in_month that takes a list of dates"nested list of int" and a month "int" and  return show many dates in the list are in the given month.

```
def number_in_month(ds,m):
    for d in ds:
        if d[1]==m:
            return 1 + number_in_month((ds - d[1]),m )
        else:
            return     number_in_month((ds - d[1]),m )
print(number_in_month([[1,2,3],[7,2,5],[6,2,5],[4,2,36],[9,2,55],[3,2,30]],2))
```

the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assing.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(number_in_month([[1,2,3],[7,2,5],[6,2,5],[4,2,36],[9,2,55],[3,2,30]],2))
  File "assing.py", line 19, in number_in_month
    return 1 + number_in_month((ds - d[1]),m )
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: What do you expect `ds - d[1]` to do?

Comment: The error you're getting is a `TypeError`, not a "recursion error" (whatever that is).

Answer (score 0):

Because the function `number_in_month` don't return any things. I don't understand the detail logic so I can't show the solution code

Comment: the function takes 2 args  ds is list of dates where each date is a list of 3 int "year, month, day"  i loop throw each item  in that list  and compare  if the second int d[1] is equal to the month m if yes then add 1 and repeat if no then remove or ignore item